# Looking for a js solver library to minimize a functions return value by varying an argument

Tags: javascript, solver

Is there a Javascript library that allows me to pass the following function, for it to find the alpha that results in the smallest return value.

```
var RMSE = runLES(this.monthlyData, this.alpha);
```

I cannot find anything in my searches because all the words relate to other more common problems in Javascript (e.g. 'minimizer' -> minifying, 'solver' -> solving equations, etc.).

Or does anyone have tips on how I would implement this myself?

EDIT: 
This is the function body:

```
function runLES(data, alpha) {
    var errors = new Array(data.length - 2);
    for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
        var Y1 = 2 * data[i - 1].noSeasonSales;
        var Y2 = data[i - 2].noSeasonSales;
        var E1 = 2 * (1 - alpha) * data[i - 1].error;
        var E2 = Math.pow(1 - alpha, 2) * data[i - 2].error;
        data[i].forecast = Y1 - Y2 - E1 + E2;
        data[i].error = data[i].noSeasonSales - data[i].forecast;
        errors[i - 2] = data[i].error;
    }
    return getRMSE(errors);
}
```

RMSE is the root of the variance plus squared mean of the errors. (Just a number).

Comment: what should the function do? asking for library is ot.

Comment: runLES is my own function. It takes its two arguments and calculates a number to return. The number will vary depending on what alpha was passed. I am looking for the alpha value that results in the lowest return value. The value of alpha is has to be between 0 and 1 (forgot that in the question).

Comment: You could try e.g. Nelder-Mead (derivative free) from https://github.com/benfred/fmin.

Comment: Looks promising. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I depends on what kind of function you have. What does `runLES()` do?

If you have an upper and lower boundary for your alpha you can use a binary search for the minimum. If you can derive your function, you could use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) on a derivative of your function.
For details look here: [Newton's method in Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method_in_optimization)

This methods will only work right if there's only one minimum. (Your function's graph is not kind of a wave)

Comment: Yes, alpha has those boundaries. But the function does not necessarily have a global minimum unfortunately. And my math skills are not good enough to figure out and use the partial derivatives anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[Alglib.js](https://github.com/Pterodactylus/Alglib.js) maximizes or minimizes a function, F(x), subject to nonlinear equality constraints having the form Gi(x)=0, inequality ones have form Hi(x)<=0. In your case you only need to minimize F(x)

```html
<script type="module">
import {Alglib} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Pterodactylus/Alglib.js@master/Alglib-v1.1.0.js'

var data = Array(
  {noSeasonSales: 100, error: 0},
  {noSeasonSales: 200, error: 0},
  {noSeasonSales: 250, error: 0},
  {noSeasonSales: 400, error: 0},
  {noSeasonSales: 500, error: 0},
  {noSeasonSales: 600, error: 0},
  {noSeasonSales: 700, error: 0},
  {noSeasonSales: 800, error: 0},
)

function getRMSE(errors) {
    let error = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
        error += Math.pow((errors[i]), 2)
    }
    return Math.sqrt(error / (errors.length))
}

var Fx = function runLES(data, x) {
  var alpha = x[0]
  var errors = new Array(data.length - 2);
  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
    var Y1 = 2 * data[i - 1].noSeasonSales;
    var Y2 = data[i - 2].noSeasonSales;
    var E1 = 2 * (1 - alpha) * data[i - 1].error;
    var E2 = Math.pow(1 - alpha, 2) * data[i - 2].error;
    data[i].forecast = Y1 - Y2 - E1 + E2;
    data[i].error = data[i].noSeasonSales - data[i].forecast;
    errors[i - 2] = data[i].error;
  }
  //console.log(data)
  return getRMSE(errors);
}.bind(null, data)
    
    
let solver = new Alglib()
solver.add_function(Fx) //Add the first equation to the solver.
//solver.add_equality_constraint(Gx_1)
//solver.add_less_than_or_equal_to_constraint(Hx_1)
//solver.add_greater_than_or_equal_to_constraint(Hx_1)

solver.promise.then(function(result) { 
  var x_guess = [0.5] //Guess the initial values of the solution.
  var s = solver.solve("min", x_guess) //Minimize the equation
  var x = solver.get_results()
      console.log("x="+x)
  console.log(solver.get_report())
  solver.remove() //required to free the memory in C++
})
</script>
```